# How to configure chef to send emails via postfix using chef handlers

Tags: email, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I am trying to configure chef handlers to send email whenever a chef client run fails following `https://docs.chef.io/handlers.html` . In the example here email is being sent via SMTP server. I don't have SMTP Server and wanted some way to send email using postfix. How can I configure helper.rb in that case? Or is there any other way to send emails with lesser configurations?

Comment: Postfix does include a SMTP server as it is a MTA... what's the problem exactly?

Answer (score 0):

No, you'll need a relay host to send through. You can use GMail or something like AWS SES, Mailgun, Sendgrid, or Sparkpost though.